# Vertically align multiple <p> with respect to image height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to position an image to the left of two paragraphs of text such that the text is vertically centered with respect to the height of the image.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yako69m.jpg" />
    <div class="text">
        <p>line1</p>
        <p>line2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/LBUyS/

Comment: Have you tried adding `vertical-align:middle;` to `img` too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
float:left
```

for both image and p tags. 
then

```
margin-top
```

the p tag to your wish.

http://jsfiddle.net/LBUyS/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use -ve value for

```
 margin-top. 
margin-top: -12%;
```

But, you have to take care in media query also. Use `%` instead of `PX`. Hope this will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it using CSS table-cells.

For the HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-panel">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yako69m.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>line1</p>
        <p>line2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Wrap the image in a `div` similar to what you did for the `div.text` that wraps the `p` elements.

Apply the following CSS:

```css
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 80%; /* optional */
    margin: 0 auto; /* optional if you want to center wrapper */
}
.img-panel, .text {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.img-panel {
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.img-panel img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.text {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Apply `display: table` to the wrapper, and then `display: table-cell` to the two child `div`'s.

Use the `vertical-align: top` property to set the image to the top of its parent element, and then `vertical-align: middle` to position the paragraphs to the middle of the right table-cell element.

As long as the image is taller then the content to the right, you will get the layout that you need.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/uG8G2/

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS flexbox (might want to add vendor prefixes for better browser support):

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
img {
    width:20%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/LBUyS/4/